# Do console cheats disable achievements?

Tags: steam, fallout-4

Title sums it up, but I'll break it down into two parts.

Part 1: Will console commands disable achievements in Steam?
Part 2: If achievements are disabled will it be forever or just for game session?

Comment: Every game is different, can't be possible, New Vegas was not made by Bethesda Soft. but Obsidian Ent.

Comment: This question has still been asked, though, and for Fallout 4 too. Can't remember where the first question is though.

Comment: @Texenox Ok, please provide a link when you can

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden Hmm, interesting, but no official info there!

Comment: @Dionysus - It doesn't need to be 'official word'. Plenty of people have tested this and it has shown to have no effect on unlocking achievements. I have personally used setav and tcl many times and still earn achievements regularly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to say they probably don't.

I think this because Bethesda plans to bring mods to all platforms, and some will need access to some of the 'cheat' commands.

A good example from Skyrim is the 'showracemenu' command, without TGM it would wipe your levels and perks out, some people are going to build benign mods that need that functionality.  Now consoles may have issues because mods will probably need to be greenlit before they are pushed out, which would allow them to be tagged as cheat mods.

Comment: Wait, where does it say that Bethesda is planning that? Could you add an external source, by any chance?

Comment: [This](http://wccftech.com/fallout-4-mod-tools-exclusive-pc-mods-playable-consoles/) for example